# Text warp effect in Photoshop or Illustrator

Tags: graphics, photoshop, vector-graphics

[logo http://mlfuentes.webdesigndarwen.co.uk/austinsroofing.jpg](http://mlfuentes.webdesigndarwen.co.uk/austinsroofing.jpg)

Hi there, I am unsure how to re-create the above text warp effect in either Photoshop or Illustrator?

I need the AUSTIN'S text to rise in the center, I have tried the text warp effects built into photoshop but they are too "rounded" and not as straight as this.

Can anybody please shed some light on his I can achieve this?

Thankyou!

Comment: Stackoverflow is really for programming questions. However, the best way to achieve this would be to convert the text to paths and move each of points of the upper half of the letters up so that are aligned with the roof. This would actually take a while. A quicker way would be to rasterise the type, duplicate it (treat the new layer as the right half and the previous one as the left half) and using warp, adjust the corners of the warp box so the text becomes angled like the roof, but remember to adjust the handles on the corners of the warp box to straighten out the text (so it's not curved)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be easy achieved both in Photoshop and Illustrator, but in Photoshop it's even easier :)

You can follow these simple steps:

1. Create the text you need.
2. Convert the text into a vector shape.
3. Duplicate this shape and broke it into 2 shapes with additional rectangle.
4. Distort both part of the word with Transform tool (Ctrl+T or Cmd+T) to achieve a perspective you need.
5. And finally merge these 2 vector shape together.

And if you need this logo in .ai format just copy and place the final vector shape into Illustrator.

That's it :) It can be done in minute.
Hope this helps you)